# Antlr4 parse postscript grammar

Tags: antlr4, grammar, postscript

I'm writing a postscript grammar, then use Antlr4 to parse .ps file.  I don't find any grammar file for postscript. Does anyone have the grammar file for postscript? Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn”t a tokenizer/lexer be enough?

Answer (score 2):

The only part of the language that *needs* a grammar is the `{` ... `}` construct. The rest can be handled by regular expressions, and in many cases the executable arrays can be implemented with extra recursion or looping patched onto a framework that is 99% regular expressions.

The description of the language is a relatively short part of the PLRM (at least the important first few sections). In brief,

1. the tokenizer scans for contiguous non-whitespace, non-delimiter (`{}[]()<>/`) characters.
2. attempt to convert to a realtype number or integertype number, convert to a name otherwise.
3. any delimiter character terminates the previous token and initiates a new token.
   a. `[` yields an executable name
   b. `]` yields an executable name
   c. `(` begins a string which may contain balanced parens and escapes
   d. `<` begins a hex string (or ASCII85 string if the next character is `~`)
   e. `/` introduces the following token as a literal name
   f. `{` accumulate tokens until matching `}` and create an executable array. The sequence of tokens may contain balanced `{` and `}` pairs which construct subarrays

Comment: I actually wrote a [PostScript scanner](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.lang.postscript/c/RlAj6RrAG6U/m/C4JQjuKaBgAJ) to test my parser combinators. It's not Antlr syntax but should show all the details expressed like a grammar. HTH

Comment: Thanks, @luser droog  I was reading your code. It's good!